# How to add comments to images using xamarin

Tags: android, image, xamarin, media

I am using xamarin forms and build sample app. The app has few fields and take image function. When user take an image, the image get saved in phone gallery and get renamed to data from fields.

I have a notes field. In notes field user can enter some text and characters. I don't want to include data from note fields to rename image.

What I want is to get the user input from notes field and save in image comments. (Please see image below).

[image comment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVABh.png)

My first question is it possible to do that. So user fill some fields, take picture, and whatever user type in notes field; it can get saved in imagedetails->comments.

**This is code to save image and rename to some data input fields.**
I am using jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin plugin to take images. 
https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin

```
        private async void Take_Photo_Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();
        if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("No Camera", ":( No camera available.", "OK");
            return;
        }

        var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
        {
            SaveToAlbum = true,
            //Directory = "Sample",

            Name = jobnoentry.Text + "-" + Applicationletter + "-" + signnoentry.Text + "-" + Phototypeentry,




    });

        if (file == null)
            return;

        MainImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
        {
            var stream = file.GetStream();
            return stream;
        });
```

You can see I assign Name of image to some data fields. But how i can add notes to annotate the image and have them in image comments.

Hope you all understand my question.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what file type is the image being stored as. Is it a .png? a .jpeg? The library's example seems to indicate it stores JPEG files.

If that's the case, look into editing EXIF data. i.e. https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Media.ExifInterface/

Comment: It does store images as JPEG files. I found this 'TAG_USER_COMMENT' on https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface#TAG_USER_COMMENT.  How I can use this in above code which i provided in my original question. It doesn't really tell  you how to utilize all these tags in your code.

Comment: @TomWilson That TAG is used as a parameter for the function `setAttribute` (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html#setAttribute(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) . You specify which attribute you are setting and the value.

Comment: So If do something like this - setAttribute (TAG_USER_COMMENT, "picture comments") - How will I call this function so it will save the comments,  to image. If you look at code in question, where I assign name to image, will I call this function after that. Not sure I will add this attribute to my code so it can save image comments. Thanks.

Comment: If I put setAttribute (TAG_USER_COMMENT, "picture comments") , just after the   Name = jobnoentry.Text ....... (line 13 in code in question), it shows errors.